# Best practices when dealing with angulars and tag attribute change (and DOM)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, attributes

Premise: I'm new to AngularJS and trying to learn it. In the following example I'm monitoring text lenght and cursor position in a textarea. It does work, indeed.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.pos = function() {
        var id = document.getElementById("myArea");
        return id.selectionStart;
    }

    $scope.len = function() {
        return $scope.myTextarea.length;
    }

    $scope.myTextarea = "Ciao, sono una textarea";

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <textarea id="myArea" ng-click ng-keyup ng-model="myTextarea" ng-trim="false"></textarea>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <div>Length: {{ len() }}</div>
    <div>Cursor position: {{ pos() }}</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

My question is: is there a more "angular" way to do it (I mean without using JQuery, or getElementById or similar)? Is there a better way to access the "selectionStart" property of the "myArea" textarea, without having to search the DOM for an ID?

In general, is there a way in AngularJS to access the element bound to an ngModel (something like "$scope.myTextarea.boundElement")?

In a previous version of this code I used to define two event handlers to get the value of selectionStart. Then I noticed that ng-click and ng-keyup simply need to be there, even without being associated to an actual function, to make the code work.

In any case they're necessary to get the correct value of selectionStart. On the other hand they're not necessary to make "length" work. I would have expected that changes to "selectionStart" were monitored "automagically" like "length" and that something like a "return $scope.myTextarea.selectionStart" would do.

Is this possible, somehow?

Comment: Answer to all your questions: write custom directive.

Comment: Ok. Just to be more specific: are you suggesting to write a custom directive to visualize the cursor position? Any quick hint how to do that? Or to implement the whole stuff via a directive?